# Django admin add record using signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I don't have problem with saving the record when the user login, the problem here is for example the user login June 19, 2022 8am and accidentally logout, I just want that 1 data inserted data per day.

```
class UserLogs(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    @receiver(user_logged_in)
    def post_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        print(user)
        insert = UserLogs(
            fullname = user,
            time_in = datetime.now()
        )
        print(insert.id)
        if insert.id.exists():
            insert.save()
        else:
            print('dont save!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the user was logged in today:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def post_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    now = timezone.now()
    old_record = UserLogs.objects.filter(
        fullname=user, time__date=now.date(),
    ).first()
    if old_record is not None:
        # Already logged in today
        return  # or update if you need

    # Otherwise create new record
    UserLogs.objects.create(
        fullname=user,
        time_in=now,
    )
```

Beware that date handling can result in unexpected results if your users are from different time zones. It will check dates against server timezone (setting `TIME_ZONE`).